# java JTable - select the entire row when cell is clicked

Tags: java, swing, jtable, selection

I would like to select the whole row when a cell is clicked.
for example: if cell at row 2 and column 4 as been clicked, I want to select all columns at row 2. (the whole row).
How can I do that?
I tried to change selectionModel to SINGLE_SELECTION, and I tried to set rowSelectionAllowed to true, but none of these helped.

Please assist.
thanks.

Comment: This is the default behaviour. Only a single cell can ever have the current "focus", but the entire row will be highlighted with the table selection background color. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for working demo code you can download and test.

Comment: what do I miss? it's doesn't do that for me //

Comment: Read the tutorial and download the demo code. If you still have a problem then post a [mcve] that demonstrate the problem We can't possibly guess what you are doing to override the default behaviour.

Comment: I suspect the actual question is how to make the "focus" extend across the entire row (not just the selection/highlight), but I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

If I've properly understood your problem, then I'm fairly sure that it can be solved by adding these two lines to your code:

```
yourTable.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
yourTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
```

Likely to arrive too late for you, but to those who, seeking solutions to the same problem, stumble upon this question, I hope this helps.

Comment: This just sets the behavior to its usual default.